# How do you leave a comment on Hacker News?

Tags: hacker-news

I don't see any links or buttons in the UI to leave a comment on anything (I'm logged in).

Comment: If you navigate to the "comments" section for the article (or "discuss" if no comments have been left yet) then there is a textbox with an "add comment" button at the top of the page. You don't need to be logged in to see this. (Or have JavaScript enabled.) Do you not see this?

Comment: @w3dk Yep, I didn't start seeing that text box until after I logged in. Once it was there, it was completely obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I think it wasn't working because I didn't have an email address for my account. When I added one, then I started seeing comment boxes in the UI.